# How to upload edges via CSV file if nodes have null IDs in Apache AGE - Error: "label_id must be 1 .. 65535"

Tags: apache-age

So I'm trying to upload graphs from CSV file in apache age.
For that I'm using the following commands,

```
SELECT create_graph('test_graph');

SELECT create_vlabel('test_graph','movie');

SELECT load_labels_from_file('test_graph','movie','/home/sarthak/Downloads/sample/movie.csv',false);
```

This works and it's for creating nodes.
Notice I've passed false flag as ID is optional as stated in the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/agload.html#load-graph-functions).

Here's movie.csv

```
~ cat movie.csv                                                  

name,released
The Matrix,1999
```

However while uploading edges I've to follow [this](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/agload.html#explanation-about-the-csv-format) csv format.
Here `start_id and end_id` corresponds to ids present in node.csv, but that I've not set.

So how can I create edges between them.

I tried with

```
SELECT create_elabel('test_graph','acted');

SELECT load_edges_from_file('test_graph', 'acted','/home/sarthak/Downloads/sample/ACTED_IN[person&movie].csv');
```

But results in error `ERROR:  label_id must be 1 .. 65535`

Here's my edge.csv

```
> cat ACTED_IN\[person\&movie\].csv                      
start_id,start_vertex_type,end_id,end_vertex_type,properties
1,Keanu Reeves,3,The Matrix,Neo
2,Carrie-Anne Moss,1,The Matrix,Trinity
3,Laurence Fishburne,2,The Matrix,Morpheus
4,Hugo Weaving,2,The Matrix,Agent Smith
```

I've checked that there's no garbage value in the csv file.

Comment: I believe you cannot create edges without first creating vertices with the property ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because you need to provide the edge label name as the `start_vertex_type` and `end_vertex_type` parameters. Here is the correct format:

```
start_id,start_vertex_type,end_id,end_vertex_type,character_name
1,Person,3,Movie,Neo
2,Person,1,Movie,Trinity
3,Person,2,Movie,Morpheus
4,Person,2,Movie,Agent Smith
```

Please note that I have changed the header from `properties` to `character_name`. The parser will use this header name as the property name when creating the edge.

However, in order to use the correct IDs, you need to ensure that each vertex has this property. You can either iterate through each vertex and add the property, or modify your vertex `.csv` file to include this additional column.